# I have Ubuntu Mate 18.10, which sudo should I install, 18.04 or 20.04?

Tags: sudo

Will there be any harm if I install sudo from Ubuntu 20.04 or sudo from Ubuntu 18.04 on my Ubuntu 18.10 system?

There is no official sudo upgrade offered for Ubuntu 18.10.

(Why I need 18.10 is complicated)

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry.  The only reason I can think of for being stuck on 18.10 was it was the last *official* release which had x86 or 32-bit ISOs (but none were available for Ubuntu-MATE anyway).  18.10 could be *force* upgraded to 19.04 (where ISOs were likewise available in the *alpha* phase) so I don't understand your being stuck on 18.10.  If you're system is x86 or 32-bit, you should return to 18.04 as both 18.10 & 19.04 are EOL now (19.04 was supported it's entire life for x86/i386 but turned off pre-eoan's release).

Comment: What do you mean by "*sudo upgrade offered for Ubuntu 18.10*" ??

Comment: @guiverc OP is using is using version 18.10 for his own reasons. Since 18.10 is EOL, OP can't get the security update for `sudo`. OP wants to know where to get the patched `sudo` from, either of the 2 LTS repositories, 18.04 or 20.04. I am voting to close this question as it is about an EOL version.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), but that's also your problem. Being EOL, mirrors can drop the release, and the main archive moves to old-releases.  Your tested & supported *release-upgrade* path is now also gone, as 18.10 upgraded to 19 04 which now too is EOL. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/

Comment: If you're worried about CVE-2021-3156, don't forget there are loads of others *unpatched* in *cosmic*.....    you should be using this a prompt to switch to a supported release to get them all patched.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 18.10 went end of life on 19 July 2019 and so is offtopic here, and is also a really bad idea to be running as it doesn't receive security updates, as you have noticed.

It would not be a good idea to forcibly install a sudo package from another version of Ubuntu. You would be better off:

- uninstalling sudo;
- recompiling the sudo source package for 18.10 with the fix applied; or
- downloading the upstream sudo source, compiling it and replacing your system sudo with that one.

But upgrading to a supported release is a better idea than all of the above.